# Open VHD with Windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a fully patched Win7 PC with XenCenter installed and VHD files registered to XenCenter.

As of now, I am unable to open a VHD file on this PC - whenever I open it in XenCenter, it wants to import the file onto a Xen Server, which is not what I want for this particular image (the vhd image is just a Windows with IE9 for browser compatibility tests).

I read that Win7 should be able to open VHD images without external tools, but I don't know how to talk my computer into this.

Comment: When you say *open*, do you mean to explore its content?

Comment: I meant "run in a VM on my local PC". I just found that "without external tools" only means "without third-party tools" - one still has to install Microsoft's "Windows Virtual PC" to be able to open the hard drive image.